# How to plot the X year survival probability(let's say X=10) from a COX regression model with the change of covariate?

Tags: r, survival-analysis, cox-regression, survival

I noticed that most codes provided for survival curve plot are about the trend of survival by time, is there any r package that can set "time" as fixed, e.g 10 years, and plot the 10-year survival probability with the change of covariates, e.g. age?

I'm using a COX regression.

Thanks!

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `predict` to get the predicted survival at any time and any level of covariates you wish. You haven't supplied your model or your data, so I will create a demo from the `survival` package's built-in `lung` data set.

```r
library(survival)

df <- survival::lung[c(2, 3, 4, 5)]
df$time <- (df$time * 2) / 365
df$status <- df$status - 1

model <- coxph(Surv(time, status) ~ age + strata(sex), df)
```

To get predictions at ten years for both sexes at a range of ages, we create a little data frame with all the variables used in our model but set to the values we want (including `status`, which is ignored, so we can set that to 0)

```r
new_data <- data.frame(age = rep(50:90, 2), sex = rep(1:2, each = 41),
                       time = 10, status = 0)
```

Now we plug this new data into `predict` with `type = "survival"` and store it in our new data frame.

```r
new_data$survival <- predict(model, newdata = new_data, type = "survival")
```

Now we can just plot the result. Here, I'll use `ggplot`:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(new_data, aes(age, survival, color = c("male", "female")[sex])) +
  geom_line(size = 1.5) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("orangered", "deepskyblue3"), name = "Sex") +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent) +
  labs(title = "10 year survival according to age") +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(text = element_text(size = 16))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-03-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>